# Fixing an issue regarding Services.msc or Services with PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, shell, terminal, windows-services

Alongside my problem, I would appreciate some insight on the special windows Services app if possible, in the case I am not correctly understanding how this all works. Thank you.

**Context:

I am writing a PowerShell script that manually creates a windows service and also deletes or cleans it up if it exists. My script attempts to stop the service beforehand.**

**The Problem:

When I create and delete services in within my PowerShell script, they can be blocked by the services app being open**

I'm thinking potential solutions could be

- Getting sc.exe create and delete commands to fully accomplish the deletion and creation of services via PowerShell and not just be marked
- Being able to properly check whether Services.msc or Services is open(active on the taskbar)

Any help is appreciated!

I'd like to preface this with saying I may be mixing up my results with sc.exe create and delete but either way I believe I had an issue here.

I have decided so far to try and check if the services app is open or not but haven't been able to get this to work. In my experience of creating and deleting windows services, I have had this app block the ability to run those commands in PowerShell. An example would be (sc.exe delete "SomeService") giving feedback such as "x is marked for deletion" but doesn't delete it for instance until it is closed or the service itself is stopped.

I've also tried killing the task or process for Services but not sure I can even do this. I have not been able to bypass the permissions for it.

Comment: Just food for thought, but within your script, can't you just lookup if specific processes are running (the ones from your service) and kill them before modifying your service ?
Example :
- is process running ?
- If so, stop service
- still runing ? If so kill it
- modify your service

Comment: Thanks for the response. In my script, I do attempt to stop the service, but I've noticed sometimes it isn't able to delete it correctly. I wonder if potentially the stop command needs to halt to process the stop in order to delete it immediately afterwards?  Not sure why but I am not always able to get the script to properly delete the service after this check. That's also why I came to the conclusion that the services application itself was causing the issue by being open.

Comment: From my experience, when you can't delete a service, it's because the linked process is still in running state (this is why for example you get the long wait time from MMC when trying to stop a service). Most of my automated scripts linked to services force kill processes before service deletion and it does the trick. Not necessarily best practices though

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in comment, here is a snippet that could work for you

```
# Set the name of the service and process to check for
$serviceName = "Application1Service"
$processName = "application1.exe"

# Check if the service is running
if (Get-Service $serviceName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"}) {
    # Stop the service
    Stop-Service $serviceName

    # Check if the process is running
    if (Get-Process $processName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        # Kill the process
        Stop-Process -Name $processName -Force
    }

    # Delete the service (CmdLet available from Powershell 6.0)
    Remove-Service $serviceName
}
```